# How to get the charsets supported by Perl's String::Multibyte

Tags: string, perl

I am working with the [`String::Multibyte`](https://metacpan.org/module/String::Multibyte) module, and it seems that `String::Multibyte->new()` accepts a charset as the first argument and throws an exception if the charset is not supported. I think the supported charsets are defined by `*.pm` files in a specific directory.

What is the most robust way to get the supported charsets? Is getting the files the only way?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the value of this module, and the source code has some questionable things, but, apart from that, it looks like you are going to have to use a method similar to what the module itself does:

```
use File::Basename qw( basename );
use File::Spec::Functions qw( catdir );
require String::Multibyte;

my $dir = catdir(basename($INC{'String/Multibyte.pm'}), 'Multibyte');
opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Cannot open charset dir '$dir': $!";
my @charsets = grep s/[.]pm\z//, readdir $dh;
close $dh;
```

The code is untested.